# How do I capture response of form.submit in React-native WebView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview, expo

I have a WebView component in my react-native app to make form submitting to an external API
I am looking for a way to capture the response of form.submit in order to know the status of the request and to use the response in my app

```
<WebView source={{
      html: '<BODY onload="document.forms[0].submit();"/>\n'+
      '<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="https://sbcheckout.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentPage"  id=form1 name=form1>\n' +
        `<INPUT  NAME="access_code" value="${access_code}">\n`+
        `<INPUT  NAME="language" value="${language}">\n` +
        `<INPUT  NAME="merchant_identifier" value="${merchant_identifier}">\n` +
        `<INPUT  NAME="merchant_reference" value="${merchant_reference}">\n` +
        `<INPUT  NAME="service_command" value="${service_command}">\n` +
        `<INPUT  NAME="card_number" value="${card_number}" >\n` +
        `<INPUT  NAME="expiry_date" value="${expiry_date}">\n` +
        `<INPUT  NAME="card_security_code" value="${card_security_code}">\n` +
        `<INPUT  NAME="signature" value=${signture}>\n` +
        '\n' +
        '<input type="submit" value="Submit">' +
        '\n' +
        '\t</form>'
        }}
      style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
    />
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will capture the response in webview only. You won't be getting the response out from the webview to react -native.
It will be better to perform your task within native app rather than opening a webview. As I can see you are making use of a form data simply so there is no use of opening this form in webview, rather open the same form in react native only and store the output and use wherever you want to use.

Comment: Do you know another way to make a  form request in react-native rather then webView?